# Should there be a controller for items inside model?

Tags: ember.js

I have data that contains "city" and every city might contain many (or none) "houses".
It should display list of cities, and when opening some city it should display information about that city and list of cities.
So I defined route for "Cities" and "CitiesHouse", and ArrayController for Cities, and [Object]Controller for CitiesHouse. All data comes from ajax request

```
model: return Ember.$.getJSON(..)
```

For cities json returns array of items, for house it returns json record/object, with information about that house and it "floors" field, that is array and contain data about floors in that house.
In house view it's displayed very simple

```
{{#each file in model.floors}} {{file.description}} {{/each}}
```

Everything would be very nice, but it starts failing when I try to bind properties to floor field

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="showDetails"}}
```

So how controllers/routes design should be done when you have such model?
Can be "floors" defined with separate controller (and than every item in floor have it's own controller)?
I'm using emberjs 1.11.

To clarify a bit: 
what I'm wondering, is if data model is something like this:
itemsList * -- 1 Item 1 -- * subItemsList
Should subItemsList be represented as separate controller (there is no to get data only for subItemsList, only data for Item can be retrieved)?

How to observe separate array items in controller? So there is separate bindings for every item in array.

```
Ember.ObjectController.extend({ isCheckedChanged[]: function(){...}.observes('isChecked') });
```

Comment: A failing bin at emberjs.jsbin.com would make it easier for anyone to answer ur question.

Comment: I believe binding does not work when you use quotes, try ```checkedBinding=showDetails``` and see "Bound" vs "Unbound" http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_input